Was there a famine in China in 1906–07 that killed 20–25 million?
Wikipedia has a page on this but its "factual accuracy is disputed":

This Chinese famine was directly caused by the 1906 China floods (April–October 1906) ...
Two modern commentaries estimate the total famine deaths in the range of 20–25 million, implying that most of the population of northern Anhui and northern Jiangsu population were wiped out, but offering no explanation on how the calculation is made.


One of the key primary sources in English seems to be Kirton who states " How many of these people are affected... it is impossible for me to say with any approach to the most primal degree of accuracy." Bill Kte'pi apparently gave the 25 million figure but I don't see anyone else supporting or denying that except that 10 million seems like the more common estimate at the time.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). Did you check the sources on the Wikipedia page? Did you google?

In the "Reports and Accounts, 1910-1911" by the Central China Famine Relief Fund (1912) there is a chapter on "Honan" and another on "Anhui" two of the provinces affected by flood referred to by the OP. The flood seems to be the major focus of the entire report. The report on Honan reads as follows in part:

Right Rev. Wm. C. White, Anglican Bishop in Honan, wrote from Kaifeng,
under date of May 2, 1911, as follows: I have just returned from the
famine region in the east of the Province... Many a tragic tale had
these people to tell of parties dwindled by starvation to one half and
even one third the original number. Most of them were still living on
roots and bark, the blades of new wheat, and 'kaoliang' straw, and the
mortality must be even greater than in the winter, for we occasionally
saw bodies in the fields usually being eaten by dogs, and heard
gruesome tales of survivors eating the dead bodies of their
comrades... A great deal of seed grain is being taken east, but all
under armed escort, and we daily heard stories of grain being
looted...But Kweiteh is practically only on the fringe of the famine
district, the famine centre in Monan being the districts of Yungcheng
and Siayi. The Chinese say that one-fifth of the population of
Yungcheng have succumbed to the famine. If this is so, and if the
census of this district taken last January is approximately correct,
it means that the appalling number of over 200,000 have died of
starvation.

Throughout the report there are similar eyewitness testimonies to the effects of the flood and the resulting starvation. The estimates of the death toll tend to be specific to various cities or regions (such as the one above) and in the report on Anhui the author writes:

It is impossible to make even an estimate of the number who have lost
their lives in this famine. No one, so far as I know, has the data
available for such an estimate. Nothing but a careful census, covering
large sections of the country, can show how many have perished of
famine and of the resulting famine fevers. The death rate has
undoubtedly been a large one, notwithstanding the relief that has been
given. It would undoubtedly have been very greatly increased had not
so much help been sent in. There is not a village without a
considerable list of the dead. Many have left home to try and exist by
begging in more fortunate centres who have perished by the roadside or
have been lost to sight. Families have been scattered, wives and
children sold in large numbers, and many have been reduced to a
condition of permanent beggary.


I don't understand how this answers the Q. The only estimate given is "over 200,000", which is two orders of magnitude below the 20-25M asked about in the question. So is  "No" your answer to the question?

@user103496 The "answer" is subsumed by the second quotation in my answer: "It is impossible to make even an estimate of the number who have lost their lives in this famine. No one, so far as I know, has the data available for such an estimate." (Rev. E.C. Lobenstein June 12, 1911.) However, if the estimate of 20% of the population (see first quotation) were accurate, then the 20-25 million could easily be true.

That quote was made in 1911 and by a reverend (not a professional historian). Why couldn't professional historians have made progress since?
